# Retornar o elemento faltante de uma lista de numeros inteiros

Tags: python

Fazer uma função chamada faltante que, dada uma lista com N − 1 inteiros numerados de 1 a N, descubra qual número inteiro deste intervalo está faltando. Não estou conseguindo achar um código que englobe qualquer lista de inteiros.

```
def faltante(L: List[int]):
''' teste '''
    posicao = 0
    while L[posicao] < len(L):
        if posicao+1 == L[posicao]:
            posicao = posicao + 1
        break
    return posicao+1
```

**Saída**

```
print(faltante([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]))
```

> retorna 2, esperava 4

Comment: Marco, boa tarde! Insira no seu código um exemplo de uma lista que deseja testar e o resultado esperado. Abraços!

Comment: Os números sempre estarão em ordem crescente?

Comment: Sim. Estarão em ordem crescente

Comment: Vai faltar apenas um número ou podem faltar mais de um número na lista?

Answer (score 5):

Você pode comparar se o próximo elemento é a soma do elemento atual + 1, caso seja diferente adicionamos o item atual + 1 (que deveria ser o valor real) a lista, que está dentro da função, e ao final da execução retornamos essa lista:

```
def faltante(lista):
    lst_return = []    
    
    for i in range(len(lista) - 1): 
        if lista[i + 1] != lista[i] + 1 :
            lst_return.append(lista[i] + 1)
            
    return lst_return
```

Saída:

```
print(f'Números faltantes: {faltante([1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10])}')
Números faltantes: [4, 9]
```

---

Uma alternativa para listas como `[1, 5, 7, 9]`:

é utilizar o range:

```
lst_return.append(list(range(lista[i] + 1, lista[i + 1])))
```

Saída:

```
print(f'Números faltantes: {faltante([1, 5, 7, 9])}')
Números faltantes: [[2, 3, 4], [6], [8]]
```

Uma forma mais geral:

```
def faltante(lista):
    lst_return = []    
        
    if lista[0] != 0:
        lst_return.append(list(range(0, lista[0])))
        
    for i in range(len(lista) - 1):    
        if lista[i + 1] != lista[i] + 1 :
            lst_return.append(list(range(lista[i] + 1, lista[i + 1])))
            
    return lst_return
```

Saída:

```
print(f'Números faltantes: {faltante([5, 7, 9])}')
Números faltantes: [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [6], [8]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Para verificarmos **TODOS** os números que porventura esteja faltando em uma lista **qualquer**, basta utilizarmos o código abaixo.

**NOTA:** Este código pode englobar **quaisquer** listas de inteiros - crescente, decrescente, alternada, com valores positivos, com valores negativos, com valor nulo e com valores positivos, negativos e nulos.

```
def faltante(lis):
    menor = min(lis)
    maior = max(lis)
    faltando = list()
    for c in range(menor, maior + 1):
        if c not in lis:
            faltando.append(c)
    return faltando


numeros = list(map(int, input('Digite alguns números: ').split()))

print(f'Os números faltantes são:\n{faltante(numeros)}')
```

Observe que quando executamos este código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite alguns números:` . Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os número que desejarmos, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`.

Após a inserção dos valores, os mesmo serão montados na lista `números` e, em seguida, a mesma é passada como parâmetro para a função `faltante`. Chegando lá, é calculado o `menor` e `maior` valor da referida lista. Posteriormente, o **for** percorrerá o `range(menor, maior + 1)` e, com o auxílio do bloco `if`, é verificado se cada elemento da respectiva interação **não pertence** à lista - parâmetro `lis`. Caso o respectivo elemento não pertença à lista, o mesmo é adicionado à lista `faltando`.

Depois destas operações a lista de números faltantes é exibida.

**Vamos testa a execução do código?**

**Exemplo 1:**

Vamos digitar os valores...

```
1 2 3 5 6 7 8 10
```

A saída será:

```
[4, 9]
```

**Exemplo 2:**

Vamos digitar os valores...

```
1 5 7 9
```

A saída será:

```
[2, 3, 4, 6, 8]
```

**Exemplo 3:**

Vamos digitar os valores:

```
1 12 13 15 17 20
```

A saída será:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 16, 18, 19]
```

Observe que em ambos exemplos, o código foi capaz de verificar e exibir **TODOS** os valores **FALTANTES** em uma só lista e em ordem crescente.

**Outra coisa**, ao calcular o `menor` e o `maior` valor da lista já habilito a função para trabalhar com valores que também não estejão em ordem - crescente ou decrescente.

**Exemplo 4:**

Vamos digitar os valores:

```
12 9 2 5 18
```

A saída será:

```
[3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
```

**Exemplo 5:**

Vamos digita os valores:

```
4 20
```

A saída será:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

**Exemplo 6:**

Vamos digitar os valores:

```
-10 -3 6 12
```

A saída será:

```
[-9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

**Resumo**

Este código é capaz de identificar e exibir **todos** os valores faltantes de uma lista de números **inteiros** - positivos, negativos e nulos - independentemente da ordem - crescente, decrescente ou alternada - que os valores se apresentarem.

Answer (score 3):

Como *parece* ser um exercício, "provavelmente querem" que você faça com um *loop* simples. Mas apenas para deixar registrado, você pode resolver usando [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set):

```
def faltante(numeros):
    # intervalo contendo todos os números possíveis (baseado na lista de números)
    # vai do menor valor existente da lista até o maior
    intervalo = range(min(numeros), max(numeros) + 1)
    return list(set(intervalo) - set(numeros))
```

Ou, juntando tudo em uma linha:

```
def faltante(numeros):
    return list(set(range(min(numeros), max(numeros) + 1)) - set(numeros))
```

A ideia é gerar 2 `set`'s:

- o primeiro `set` contém todos os números possíveis. Estou considerando que o intervalo vai do menor número existente na lista até o maior número existente na lista. Isso não cobre os casos em que o primeiro ou o último estão faltando. Por exemplo, se a lista for `[2, 5, 8]`, o número 1 está faltando? Ou eu considero apenas os números a partir do 2? Estou considerando que é o segundo caso (que também é o que as outras respostas fizeram).

  Aliás, também existe a limitação de não considerar o caso em que o maior número está faltando: se a lista for `[1,2,3]`, o 4 está faltando? Esta solução - e as outras respostas também - consideram que não (se bem que, em um caso mais geral como `[2, 5, 9]`, como saber se o 10 está faltando ou não? Nesse caso acho melhor considerar que o 9 é o limite máximo - mas logo abaixo deixo uma alternativa para resolver isso).
- o segundo `set` contém apenas os números da lista.

Subtraindo os `set`'s, temos os números faltantes, e eu transformo o `set` resultante em lista (embora não seja necessário, se você apenas quiser os números, tanto faz a estrutura em que eles são retornados).

Vale lembrar que um `set` não garante a ordem dos elementos, então a lista nem sempre retornará os números em ordem (mas se quiser, pode usar [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) para retornar a lista ordenada):

```
def faltante(numeros):
    return sorted(list(set(range(min(numeros), max(numeros) + 1)) - set(numeros)))
```

Sobre o problema do limite mínimo e máximo, você ainda pode fazer desta forma:

```
def faltante(numeros, minimo = None, maximo = None):
    if minimo is None:
        minimo = min(numeros)
    if maximo is None:
        maximo = max(numeros)
    intervalo = range(minimo, maximo + 1)
    return sorted(list(set(intervalo) - set(numeros)))

print(faltante([1, 2, 3, 5])) # 4

# falta o 5
print(faltante([1, 2, 3, 4], maximo=5))

# falta o 1
print(faltante([2, 3, 4, 5], minimo=1)) # 1

# falta o -1, 0 e 1, além do 6 e 7
print(faltante([2, 3, 4, 5], minimo=-1, maximo=7)) # [-1, 0, 1, 6, 7]
```

Assim, eu posso parametrizar os valores que são considerados. Por exemplo, em uma lista como `[1,2,3]`, eu posso indicar que o 4 está faltando passando o parâmetro `maximo=4` - e se eu não passar nenhum valor, ele usa a lógica anterior, de pegar o menor e maior valor da lista como os limites.

Claro que esse algoritmo não é lá muito eficiente, já que chamar [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) e [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) separadamente percorre a lista 2 vezes, e a própria criação de `set`'s (e a ordenação da lista ao final) também têm um custo adicional.

---

Mas **no caso específico do exercício** (**sempre** são números de 1 a N, somente um deles **com certeza** está faltando e eles sempre estarão em ordem crescente), dá para fazer assim:

```
def faltante(numeros):
    if numeros[0] != 1: # ver se o 1 está faltando
        return 1
    for i, n in enumerate(numeros):
        if i == len(numeros) - 1 or n + 1 != numeros[i + 1]:
            return n + 1

print(faltante([1, 2, 3, 5])) # 4

# falta o 5
print(faltante([1, 2, 3, 4])) # 5

# falta o 1
print(faltante([2, 3, 4, 5])) # 1
```

Eu uso [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para iterar pelos elementos e seus respectivos índices. Depois, basta ver se eu cheguei no último elemento (para o caso do último estar faltando), ou se o elemento seguinte não é igual ao atual + 1. Em ambos os casos o elemento que falta é o atual + 1.

Só que antes do *loop* tem que incluir uma verificação especial para o caso do `1` estar faltando.

Mas se a ideia é ter uma solução mais geral, basta usar `set` ou algum dos algoritmos das outras respostas.

Comment: Posso ter analisado errado (sono), mas na solução com conjuntos é arriscado utilizar `max(numeros) + 1` como limite máximo pois como a lista é numerada de 1 a N, se for o próprio N que não está na lista a sua solução iria considerar apenas até N-1, não?

Comment: @Woss Sim, existe essa limitação. Acho que não tem muito jeito. Se a ideia é considerar somente o caso do exercício (sempre números de 1 a N, somente um está faltando), o loop me parece a melhor opção. Mas em um caso genérico como `[2, 7, 9]`, não tem como saber qual o limite máximo (é o 9? algum outro número maior?) De qq forma, adicionei umas observações sobre isso, obrigado!

Comment: Poderia receber N por parâmetro também, já que ele parametriza o problema xD

Comment: @Woss Mas é claro! Acho que estou com sono também, devia ter pensando nisso antes. Atualizei a resposta, obrigado mais uma vez :-)

Answer (score 2):

Veja um programa baseado no seu, com algumas alterações:

```
def faltantes(L):
    if L:                             # se L tem conteudo...
        elemento = L[0]               # ...pego o primeiro elemento
        posicao = 1                   # e aponto para o 2o elemento
        while posicao < len(L):       # enquanto posicao nao chegar ao fim de L
            # se elemento *não* for antecessor a L na posicao atual...
            if (elemento + 1) < L[posicao]: 
                elemento += 1         # incremento elemento...
                yield elemento        # ... e devolvo um gerador com este elemento
            else:                     # senao...
                elemento = L[posicao] # ...tomo o elemento atual e
                posicao += 1          # ando para a proxima posicao de L
    
# programa
print('Primeira lista')
for i in faltantes([1,2,3, 5,6,7,8]):
  print(i)

print('Segunda lista')
for i in faltantes([]):
  print(i)

print('Terceira lista')
for i in faltantes([2, 4,5, 7, 9]):
  print(i)
```